# Scaling out xConnect Collection and Collection Search

Tags: xconnect, scaling

On Sitecore 9.0.2 on-premise we want to scale out the xConnect Collection and Collection Search Service.

According to [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/xconnect-collection-search-service.html) we need to perform steps mentioned below to achieve that:

1. We need to introduce `xconnect.collection.search` and `xconnect.collection.search.certificate` in the `connectionstring.config`.
2. Then we need to edit the `\App_Config\Sitecore\XConnect.Client.Configuration\Sitecore.XConnect.Client.config` file and update the `searchConnectionStringName` to the new entry in `connectionstring.config` on every core role that requires access to the xConnect Search service in our case its CM and CDs.

But it is not quite clear in the documentation that where we need to update configuration for the `xconnect.collection.search.certificate` or just adding it to the `connectionstring.config` will suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tyler said first of all we definitely need to install two dedicated instances for xConnect Collection and xConnect Collection Search. Make sure both are up and running using valid certificates.

Then modify `\App_Config\Sitecore\XConnect.Client.Configuration\Sitecore.XConnect.Client.config`on Content Management, Content Delivery (Also Processing and Reporting if those are scaled). In this config both `collectionConnectionStringName` and `searchConnectionStringName` have the same value OOTB as `xconnect.collection`. Update a different value for `searchConnectionStringName` (we used `xconnect.search`).

[image]

Now in `\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config` on Content Management, Content Delivery (Also Processing and Reporting if those are scaled), we need to add a new connection string for `xconnect.search`. This should point to your xConnect Collection Search instance and obviously like others you need to provide the valid certificate thumbprint which should match with the thumbprint mentioned in `\App_Config\AppSettings.config` on xConnect Collection Search instance.

So we were confused about the configuration changes to add the new setting for xConnect Collection Search Thumbprint in `connectionstring.config`. Hence it must be the value we used for `searchConnectionStringName` concatenated with "*.certificate*". In our case it is `xconnect.search.certificate`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do an install using SIF (Sitecore Install Framework)? If you did you'll find in your AppSettings.config within the Sitecore xConnectSearch site a setting for validateCertificateThumbprint. This value is used in your CM and CD (Also I think the Reporting site as well) in the connectionstrings.config and must reference the same thumbprint.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- YOUR XConnect Search URL-->
  <add name="xconnect.collection" connectionString="https://www.xconnectSearchURL.com" />
  <!-- YOUR XConnect Search Certificate-->
  <add name="xconnect.collection.certificate" connectionString="StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=HEREGOESTHETHUMBPRINT" />
</connectionStrings>
```

That thumbprint is from a cert that was generated during the SIF install. If you want to use in house generated certificates make sure the cert can be used as a client cert, can be found under Enhanced Key Usage from MMC.

Sitecore has some documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configure-connections-strings.html) but I've found it easiest to do a full scale install locally and reference the connectionstrings from the CM site.

Hope this helps,
Ty

Comment: Thanks Tyler but my question is different. Yes I installed using SIF but OOTB CM/CD/PRC/REP doesn't have separate connection string for Collection Search. What all you have is just Collection, Marketing Automation, Marketing Reporting and xDB Reference Data. I want to add a new connection string dedicated for Collection Search to scale out.

Comment: Oh gotcha, sorry read that wrong. You'd be more looking into changing the searchConnectionStringName and other settings in the Sitecore.XConnect.Client.config file (App_Config\Sitecore\XConnect.Client.Configuration). Pretty sure you'd need to make similar changes in your EXM (If seperated from CM), Marketing Automations, and xDB Processing.